# How to import text(not just digit) dataset in tensorflow in format 'tensorflow.examples.tutorials'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, dataset

How to import text/character dataset(apart from just digit/MNIST dataset) in tensorflow in a way in which MNIST is imported using  `tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data as mnist_data` ?

I searched quite a lot, to find a way in which I can import character/text/alphabet datasets into tensorflow script, in a way in which MNIST datasets are imported in most tutorials, i.e. `tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data`. I have not found any such solution.

I am building a handwritten text recognition model using deep learning. As my first step, I tried building digit recognizer following various online tutorials. In it, the import of MNIST dataset was a simple 1 line code,i.e. `tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data`. 
How can I import any other text recognition dataset, say like 'IAM handwriting database, 'UJI Pen Character Dataset', 'Chars74K dataset', etc. into my tensorflow script to build handwritten text recognition model?